# How to convert an UTC timestamp to system date and time in ABAP

Tags: timezone, abap

does anyone of you have suggestions how to convert a given UTC timestamp into the date and time of the system time zone?

Converting from an UTC timestamp to the users local time zone is easy, you could just do:

```
CONVERT TIME STAMP lv_utc_timestamp TIME ZONE sy-zonlo
          INTO DATE lv_local_date TIME lv_local_time.
```

But how to do it for the system time - system time is needed in many situations e.g. when calling the JOB_CLOSE function module. The only solution I have come up so far is like that:

```
SELECT SINGLE * FROM TTZCU INTO ls_ttzcu.
CONVERT TIME STAMP lv_utc_timestamp TIME ZONE ls_ttzcu-tzonesys
          INTO DATE lv_system_date TIME lv_system_time.
```

Is this already the best solution or can the system time zone be retrieved in another way?
Is there always a valid time zone to be expected from the entry in table TTZCU? Any ideas?

**UPDATE:** @rmtiwari suggested on twitter, that the FLAGACTIVE flag of TTZCU should also be checked, so the modified statement would be

```
SELECT SINGLE * FROM TTZCU INTO ls_ttzcu WHERE flagactive = abap_true.
CONVERT TIME STAMP lv_utc_timestamp TIME ZONE ls_ttzcu-tzonesys
          INTO DATE lv_system_date TIME lv_system_time.
```

**UPDATE2:** I have found another way, which is probably the best:

```
    cl_abap_tstmp=>systemtstmp_utc2syst(
           EXPORTING  utc_tstmp = lv_utc_timestamp  
           IMPORTING  syst_date = lv_system_date    " System Date
                      syst_time = lv_system_time    " System Time
           ).
```

Comment: I like your final solution. If it solved your problem, you should copy it into an answer.  After a couple of days you will be able to flag it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The best way seems to be:

```
cl_abap_tstmp=>systemtstmp_utc2syst(
       EXPORTING  utc_tstmp = lv_utc_timestamp  
       IMPORTING  syst_date = lv_system_date    " System Date
                  syst_time = lv_system_time    " System Time
       ).
```